# Sending email from one domain through the mailbox on a partner domain

Tags: email, dkim, spf

We have a domain hosting contract with IONOS (previously 1&1). A little background on the problem at hand. There are two domains, let's call them `main.domain` and `alias.domain` because the true mailboxes are on `main.domain` (ie. john@main.domain) but we do not wish to expose the emails and therefore everything is sent to the `alias.domain` using the senders name. This is a catchall email *@alias.domain.

For example, if we are dealing with Acme Corp we will use acme@alias.domain but the mail is actually forward to the mailbox john@main.domain for processing. This allows us to know the entity from whom the email originated. Additionally if they ever "sell" or get breached and leak the email and you begin getting spam at it, you know who did it or got compromised. Now if we need to respond to an email from say Acme sent to acme@alias.domain, we use the from address acme@alias.domain but it is actually being sent with the john@main.domain credentials.

Now recently they have changed how it works and so we can no longer do this. They now return `550 Email Not Allowed` because the "from" address is not john@main.domain but rather acme@alias.domain. This is apparently so that email sent via their system which originates from perfora.net will now have DKIM/SPF to say the email is legit even though it is being sent via their system. That's all nice and great but it messes greatly with our setup.

I am certain that we can setup the two domains to be recognized as the same which would not balk at the sender being an alias.domain address, but unfortunately I am not 100% sure how to do this and my research has suggested SPF TXT record on the domains but it does not seem to be working, likely I am doing it wrong or have it on the wrong domain or possibly IONOS is actively blocking this ability, not sure. I was hoping that a fellow professional and DevOp might be able to help me with me, I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: To clarify, is it _your_ host (IONOS) that is rejecting the 'From' address, or is it some _recipient_ server that's doing so?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Sorry I wasn't clear, yes it is IONOS that is rejecting it now.

Answer (score 1):

> my research has suggested SPF TXT record on the domains but it does not seem to be working, likely I am doing it wrong or have it on the wrong domain or possibly IONOS is actively blocking this ability

I wouldn't say they are "actively blocking" this ability; it was never an ability to begin with.

SPF, DKIM, DMARC all are **recipient**-side checks. None of them are done on the "sending" system, e.g. the IONOS server won't be doing any DKIM checks because the IONOS server is what stamps the DKIM signature on the message in the first place, and approximately the same goes for SPF.

Yes, you still need the SPF records (if they're present) to authorize IONOS to use that domain in the eyes of your recipients, but that has nothing to do with the message you describe – it's all about whether *IONOS* authorizes your account to use their mail server with that domain.

Merely placing IONOS's address in your SPF records would not tell them anything about which specific customer out of thousands the domain belongs to, and they do not want customer A to be able to send mail using a domain that's owned by customer Z.

Instead, at this stage, all checks are purely account-based: you authenticate to IONOS as a specific customer (via user accounts or perhaps via IP address ranges set in IONOS' configuration) and it grants you specific access. This configuration is practically always done statically in the mail server; it's not pulled from DNS.

So in other words, you have to *ask IONOS* to allow you to send mail from a different domain.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I figured as much with SPF, DKIM and DMARC but was hoping they are using the DNS settings to dynamically check these and hadn't considered that they are doing this statically on their end. However, that does support them "actively" blocking the ability. I call it an ability because until now it was not an issue and they are using SPF, DKIM and DMARC as their "excuse" for making this change, so hence why I expected they would honor proper setup on it, so turns out they just want to do something and their excuse was provided a la Google. I'll contact them but not holding my breath

Comment: If you say so...